# Google Doc viewer not loading Azure shared access signatures (SAS) files

Tags: azure, signature

I am using 
https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=[myurl]
For viewing external files, that works well only for url those are not having QueryString parameters in url

https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer**?** url=https://mysite.blob.core.windows.net/container4-18-1/20180427110822_Photos-HD-Desktop-Wallpaper.jpg**?**sv=2015-07-08&sr=c&sig=TawX1t9hNVUHuYdV%2FEG5%2F2it%2Bf8lYurFIQt2VXPMcTw%3D&se=2018-04-27T13%3A40%3A10Z&sp=rwl

Here, there are two "?", also I tried with encoding myurl but that doesn't worked.

Thank you!
**Prashant**

Comment: Will it be possible to share the actual blob URL?

Comment: we can not view images in google viewer